# Intermittant EOFError when downloading file via ruby OpenURI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paperclip, resque

I have a setup where a cron job periodically downloads an mp3 file from an external service (Twilio) and then uses Paperclip to upload the file to Amazon S3. The process is handled in the background by Resque.

Here is the code that handles the download from Twilio and subsequent attachment to Paperclip:

```
# Perform transfer from Twilio to S3
def self.perform(group_recording_id = nil)
  gr = GroupRecording.find(group_recording_id)
  # ...
  recording = TwilioClient.account.recordings.get(gr.external_id)

  if recording.present?
    # ....
    gr.audio_file = download_remote_file(gr.twilio_mp3_url)
    gr.save
  end
end

def download_remote_file(url)
  io = open(URI.parse(url))  

  # overrides Paperclip::Upfile#original_filename
  def io.original_filename
    base_uri.path.split('/').last
  end
  io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
end
```

This fails with `EOFError`s :

```
EOFError
end of file reached
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `sysread_nonblock'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `read_nonblock'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:312:in `block in open_http'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
/app/app/models/group_recording.rb:112:in `download_remote_file'
/app/app/models/group_recording.rb:85:in `perform'
```

The above is the most common error, but I also encountered this:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET
Connection reset by peer
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `sysread_nonblock'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `read_nonblock'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:86:in `read'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2424:in `read_body_0'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2379:in `read_body'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in open_http'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1194:in `block in transport_request'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2342:in `reading_body'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1193:in `transport_request'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:312:in `block in open_http'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_open'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
/app/app/models/group_recording.rb:113:in `download_remote_file'
/app/app/models/group_recording.rb:86:in `perform'
```

The problem is intermittant and just started occurring in heroku's production environment recently without any change in the relevant code. The app is currently on `ruby 1.9.3-p429` on heroku. The problem occurs locally as well, but somewhat less frequently. I tried the same and lower ruby versions (as low as `1.9.3-p194`).

Has anybody come across a similar issue? Searching for the error online has turned up similar errors, but in vastly different contexts.

Comment: Could it be that the source site for the file has banned your code? "Errno::ECONNRESET" means they closed the connection. I think an EOF error would point toward a similar problem, where the file was truncated prior to you receiving all the expected content.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The site in question is Twilio. The site owner's cc on file did expire recently but he updated it shortly after. In any case, why then would the error be intermittent and not always the case?

Comment: It could be intermittent for a number of reasons. Without inside information about their systems and processes anything said is pure speculation. We have things we call "biologicals" on our network who sometimes fail to enter commands consistently, failing to apply rules to all devices.

Comment: Hmm, I guess will take up the issue with Twilio next. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Not knowing Twilio, this is a total shot in the dark: Any chance that the recordings.get() function is asynchronous?  Ie, it returns a recording object before the actual bits are available on the server?  Do you get the error running it twice in a row?

Answer (score 0):

These are transient networking errors that you should expect in your code, and retry the operation (usually after a short sleep). The internet is not reliable!

You should log retries, and if you notice a spike or unusual pattern you may want to take it up with your service providers (heroku, twilio, etc) since there may be something on their end they can provide insight into.

There's nothing directly you can do to fix the problem from your code though (if it indeed did not change).